# MAUI - Lifecycle methods no longer work in BaseActivity

Tags: xamarin.android, maui

I am migrating an app from Xamarin.Android to MAUI. I am getting errors in all of the lifecycle methods. For example:

- protected override void OnPause()
- protected override void
  OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
- protected override void
  OnResume()

> Error CS0115  'BaseActivity.OnPause()': no suitable method found to
> override  AndroidAppCore (net8.0-android)

In Xamarin.Android I did not get any of these errors in BaseActivity.cs, but I do in MAUI
The lifecycle methods work in my LoginActivity in MAUI

**Activities/Base/BaseActivity.cs**:

```
namespace Common
{
    public abstract class BaseActivity : ISessionExpired, IPBottomNavBarIcon
```

**Activities/Login/LoginActivity.cs**:

```
namespace PApp
{
    [Activity]
    public class PatientLoginActivity : Common.BaseActivity
```

**Question**: What am I missing in BaseActivity ?

Answer (score 1):

From document [App lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/app-lifecycle?view=net-maui-8.0),we could know:

> .NET Multi-platform App UI (.NET MAUI) apps generally have four
> execution states: `not running`, `running`, `deactivated`, and `stopped`. .NET
> MAUI raises cross-platform lifecycle events on the `Window` class when
> an app transitions from the not running state to the running state,
> the running state to the deactivated state, the deactivated state to
> the stopped state, the stopped state to the running state, and the
> stopped state to the not running state.

[image]

And the `Window` class defines the following cross-platform lifecycle events: `Created`,`Activated`, `Deactivated`,`Stopped`,`Resumed`,`Destroying`.
These cross-platform events map to different platform events, and the following table shows this mapping:

[image]

So, you don't need to redefine the lifecycle at all, and you can use these events as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your BaseActivity doesn't inherit from any standard Android activity, hence the error.

e.g. should be

using AndroidX.AppCompat.App;

[Activity(Label = "BaseActivity")]

public class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity
{

}